# unbounded operator with no invariant subspace

Tags: operator-theory

Is there an example of an unbounded operator on a hilbert space with no invariant subspace? Or is there some other reason why we are only interested in bounded case.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, not a conclusive answer.

I'd start like this: Define $H$ - separable Hilbert space with the orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in \Bbb Z}$.

Let an operator $T:H\to H$ is given by $Te_n = (1+(n-1)^2) e_{n-1}+(1+(n+1)^2)e_{n+1}$.
Clearly, $T$ is linear and unbounded.

Now, we need to prove that $T$ has no invariant subspaces (not so trivial as I initially thought=)).